# datetimepicker.js error when loaded in div which is not in the DOM initially

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

I am creating a form and using datetimepicker.js in that. My form elements are initially hidden and when I load them in DOM for first time, Datetimepicker is working properly but from second time on-wards it starts giving error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'allowTimes' of undefined

Demo

```js
$(document).on("click", ".popup-checkbox", function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass("schedule-fullday-full")) {
    $(".popup-schedule-type").hide();
    $(".popup-schedule-fullday").show("drop", {
      direction: "down"
    }, 200);
    $(".schedule-start-date").datetimepicker();
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("schedule-fullday-time")) {
    $(".popup-schedule-type").hide();
    $(".popup-schedule-time").show("drop", {
      direction: "down"
    }, 200);
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("schedule-fullday-repeat")) {
    $(".popup-schedule-type").hide();
    $(".popup-schedule-repeat").show("drop", {
      direction: "down"
    }, 200);
  }

});
```

```css
.popup-schedule-type {
  display: none;
}

.popup-checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup-checkbox-boxes {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.17/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.17/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<div class="popup-checkbox-boxes">
  <div class="popup-checkbox schedule-fullday-full">
    Full Day
  </div>
  <div class="popup-checkbox schedule-fullday-time">
    Time Bound
  </div>
  <div class="popup-checkbox schedule-fullday-repeat">
    Repeating
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup-schedule-type popup-schedule-fullday">
  <div class="popup-input-holder">
    <div class="popup-input-wrap rq-input-fifty rq-with-label">
      <label class="rq-label">Order Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="rq-input schedule-start-date">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="popup-schedule-type popup-schedule-time">
  Add Time Bound Event
</div>
<div class="popup-schedule-type popup-schedule-repeat">
  Add Repeat Event
</div>
```

Here `popup-schedule-type` is hidden by default and shows after the jQuery call. First time `datetimepicker` element is loading correctly but from second time on-wards it starts giving error.

Comment: you need to add the exact code for HTML and included files to get  an answer try creating a snippet

Comment: I thought I am doing some minor mistake. Alright, Adding snippet.

Comment: it could be something minor but can be spotted if you can replicate the exact scenario, a running example always have a better chance to spot the error rather than looking at the code with naked eye

Comment: Hey, added the snippet. Please check if you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [**`complete`**](http://api.jquery.com/show/) parameter function of the show to populate the input field so that the field is completely shown before applying the `datetimepicker` see below demo and a few things that if you are using the options for the animation like `direction` or anyother then it is better to use the `duration` inside along with the options rather than sending as a parameter to `show`.

```
$(".popup-schedule-fullday").show('drop', {
      direction: 'down',
      duration: 200,
    }, function() {
      $(".schedule-start-date").datetimepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd HH:ii:ss"});
    });
```

```js
$(document).on("click", ".popup-checkbox", function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass("schedule-fullday-full")) {
    $(".popup-schedule-type").hide();
    $(".popup-schedule-fullday").show('drop', {
      direction: 'down',
      duration: 200,
    }, function() {
      $(".schedule-start-date").datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd HH:ii:ss"
      });
    });

  } else if ($(this).hasClass("schedule-fullday-time")) {

    $(".popup-schedule-type").hide();

    $(".popup-schedule-time").show("drop", {
      direction: "down"
    }, 200);
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("schedule-fullday-repeat")) {
    $(".popup-schedule-type").hide();
    $(".popup-schedule-repeat").show("drop", {
      direction: "down"
    }, 200);
  }

});
```

```css
.popup-schedule-type {
  display: none;
}

.popup-checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup-checkbox-boxes {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.17/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.17/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>

<div class="popup-checkbox-boxes">
  <div class="popup-checkbox schedule-fullday-full">
    Full Day
  </div>
  <div class="popup-checkbox schedule-fullday-time">
    Time Bound
  </div>
  <div class="popup-checkbox schedule-fullday-repeat">
    Repeating
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup-schedule-type popup-schedule-fullday">
  <div class="popup-input-holder">
    <div class="popup-input-wrap rq-input-fifty rq-with-label">
      <label class="rq-label">Order Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="rq-input schedule-start-date">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="popup-schedule-type popup-schedule-time">
  Add Time Bound Event
</div>
<div class="popup-schedule-type popup-schedule-repeat">
  Add Repeat Event
</div>
```

Comment: It worked. Although, I tried with a `complete` function earlier but I made a Typo in that. Thanks anyway for the help.